# Why my Android mobile (Samsung Galaxy Young Duos) is vibrating even if it is not in vibration mode?

Tags: vibration, samsung-galaxy-y-duos

In Samsung Galaxy Young Duos, It vibrates even if the vibration mode is off. Why is this happening? How to fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you've misunderstood what vibration mode is. The sound control has three settings:-

1. Sound on: the phone will ring and vibrate normally. You can turn vibration on or off for each notification individually in that app's settings.
2. Vibrate: the phone will still vibrate, but not make noise. In this state, any notification that would make a sound will vibrate **instead**. If the notification would have vibrated, it still does.
3. Silent: notifications and incoming calls will not cause vibration or noise.

Any notifications which have vibration enabled by the app will vibrate in either sound on or vibration mode: only silent mode will disable vibration. Also, if **Vibrate when ringing** is turned on in **Settings** → **Sound**, then incoming calls will make the phone vibrate in sound on mode as well as in vibration mode.

Answer (score 1):

May be a bug or something. Restore factory settings after making a back-up of important files.
*Note - Check the settings once again. You might have turned on the vibration.*